# Updating number of votes with a "Like" button

Tags: performance, swift, memory-optimization, parse-platform

I have a "Like" button in my iOS app that updates the votes every time it's tapped. Just like Facebook, Instagram, ProductHunt, etc.

I have a custom cell where that `IBAction` and `IBOutlet` is declared and that's where I'm making the query to the Parse db to update the UI (initially I'm querying the vote values from the other file from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.) In the custom cell file, I also created a delegate method, with a Protocol type that I'm accessing in my `TableViewController` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

I'm a bit of a newbie and studying the MVC data structure (assuming that's the biggest issue here), so please be easy on me!

Here is the code in the custom cell:

```
protocol CellButtonDelegate {

    func buttonClicked(cell : PFTableViewCell)

}
var delegate : CellButtonDelegate?

class FeedTableViewCell: PFTableViewCell {

    var delegate : CellButtonDelegate?

    var parseObject:PFObject?


    internal var buttonEnabled : Bool? {

        get {

            return loveOutlet.enabled

        } set {

            loveOutlet.enabled = newValue!
        }
    }

 @IBAction func loveButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        if(parseObject != nil) {

            if var votes: Int? = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
                votes!++

                parseObject!.setObject(votes!, forKey: "votes")
                parseObject!.saveInBackground()

                print(votes!)
            }

            delegate?.buttonClicked(self)
        loveOutlet.enabled = false

        }

    }
```

Here is the code in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {

        var cell: FeedTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? FeedTableViewCell

        if(cell == nil) {

            cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("FeedTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? FeedTableViewCell
        }

        objects![indexPath.row]

        if let pfObject = objectArray?[indexPath.row] {
                     cell?.parseObject = object 
var votes: Int? = pfObject["votes"] as? Int
            if votes == nil {
                votes = 0 
            }


            cell?.delegate = self

            let isEnabled = pfObject["isEnabled"] as! Int
            if isEnabled == 1 {

                cell?.buttonEnabled = true

            } else {

                cell?.buttonEnabled = false

            }

            print(pfObject["isEnabled"] as? Bool)
}

}


func buttonClicked(cell: PFTableViewCell) {

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

    var object : PFObject = objectArray![indexPath!.row] as! PFObject

    object["isEnabled"] = 0
    objectArray?.removeAtIndex((indexPath?.row)!)
    objectArray?.insert(object, atIndex: (indexPath?.row)!)


}
```

Currently, when the button is tapped, the UI updates, but it *also* sends a query to the db (the activity indicator/internet indicator at the top right of the iPhone is spinning every time I "like" something).

When I use other apps, like Facebook for example, the query isn't being immediately sent and updated, it does it at a later point (don't understand when or how; can't figure that out but it does seem more efficient).

Lastly, sometimes an individual cell updates, and on other (awful) days the vote appears for every 3rd cell. Trying to figure this out for days.

**In summary:** ultimately, I want to optimize the query for voting in an iOS app. How do Facebook, Instagram and everyone else do it so smoothly?

Comment: Top apps use a technique called optimistic programming. They assume the like will get sent to their server so they update it locally to appear faster. You can read more here http://www.fastcodesign.com/1669788/the-3-white-lies-behind-instagrams-lightning-speed but its a fairly complicated task to construct a model that can compare local "truth" with server-side truth

Comment: Wow, great article. Will look deeper into this. But yes I agree, this is fairly complicated. I should be tackling other issues in the meantime! And then get to this if and when the time calls for it! Thank you

Comment: Definitely, always be conscious of premature optimisation -> http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm new to programming so these tips help out a lot. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Formatting

On the whole, there are several indentation problems through out your code.  Here is made the most obvious example:

```
        if let pfObject = objectArray?[indexPath.row] {
                     cell?.parseObject = object 
var votes: Int? = pfObject["votes"] as? Int
```

The second line has two extra levels of indentation over what it should have.  The third line needs three more indentation levels to be in the correct place.

Xcode will pretty much put every single line of code exactly where it belongs.  All you have to do to get your indentation correct is simply not fight Xcode.  Even if you disagree with Xcode about how something should be indented, it's usually a lot easier to just do it Xcode's way because everyone else tends to give in to Xcode... and it's a lot less effort.  (For a personal example, I tend to feel like `case` statements within a `switch` should be indented one level from the `switch` statement, but Xcode disagrees... and it's a lot less work for me to just let Xcode have it its way.)

---

#### Delegates

> ```
> var delegate : CellButtonDelegate?
> ```

Delegates should always be `weak`.  Without making a delegate `weak`, you're almost always setting up some sort of a retain cycle.  But what's more important, people expect for delegates to be marked as `weak`.  If you want to replicate the typical "delegate" pattern, but for some reason need the default `strong` reference, then you need to call your property by something other than "delegate".

---

#### Computed Properties

I have several comments about this property:

```
internal var buttonEnabled : Bool? {

    get {

        return loveOutlet.enabled

    } set {

        loveOutlet.enabled = newValue!
    }
}
```

First of all, `internal` is the default access level.  As you marked nothing else as `public` or `private`, *everything* in your code actually has this `internal` access level.  Above all else, we should prefer consistency.  If you're going to mark `internal` things with the `internal` keyword, you're now going to need to mark every property, method, extension, protocol, class, struct, enum, and function (and whatever else I forgot) with its access modifier.  Anything else is inconsistent.  But marking them all is too verbose.  We all know (or should know) that `internal` is the default level, and if we mark all the internal things as `internal`, it just becomes an unconstructive cluttered keyword.  I would only ever recommend marking something as `internal` in a class where basically everything else is already marked as `public` or `private`.  In that case, `internal` indicates "No, I didn't forget to mark this one--yes, it really is internal, I promise."

Next, there's a whole lot of white space in this.  In fact, you consistently have a ton of vertical white space throughout the entirety of your code.  Let's use white space more constructively, shall we?  Every single line of this property is all associated to this property.  By eliminating the blank lines in the middle, it helps the eye associate all of these lines together visually (in a way far more immediately obvious than the curly braces do).

Finally, let's talk about optionals... Your `loveOutlet` doesn't appear to be defined in this file, so I don't know if it is an optional or if it is a non-optional but the `enabled` property is optional.  I don't know what has led you to marking this `buttonEnabled` property as a `Bool?` rather than a non-optional `Bool`, but based on the force-unwrapping in your setter, it seems clear that this should probably be a non-optional.  We should allow the user to pass `nil` for the `buttonEnabled` property--how can that even make sense?  It clearly doesn't make sense, because if they ever do, we simply crash.  This is supremely bad design.  Swift gives you the power to clearly dictate which properties can and cannot be set to `nil`.  What you've done here is created a property that can be set to `true`, `false`, or "crash my app please".

So more realistically, this property should look about like this:

```
var buttonEnabled: Bool {
    get {
        return loveOutlet.enabled
    } 
    set {
        loveOutlet.enabled = newValue
    }
}
```

If `loveOutlet` is optional (in this case, for it to compile, it'd have to be an implicitly unwrapped optional), or its `enabled` property is optional, then we can go for one of these two options in the `get`:

```
loveOutlet?.enabled ?? false
```

or

```
loveOutlet.enabled ?? false
```

---

#### if true then true else false

```
let isEnabled = pfObject["isEnabled"] as! Int
if isEnabled == 1 {

    cell?.buttonEnabled = true

} else {

    cell?.buttonEnabled = false

}
```

Here, we see another issue with overuse of vertical white space, poor optional management, and a pattern that I simply don't understand: `if true then true else false`.

This `as! Int` can cause an app crash in multiple ways.  First, the value can simply not exist for the key.  Second, the value could exist, but not be convertible to an `Int`.  If this is a dictionary representing JSON, the value could be a string, floating point, or bool.  If it's not representing JSON, it could be anything.  But we can rewrite this safer and using significantly fewer lines:

```
cell?.buttonEnabled = (pfObject["isEnabled"] as? Int) == 1
```

Although, arguably, we'd really want to fix our model so that the value for the `"isEnabled"` key is actually a bool, then we can write something that makes a bit more sense:

```
cell?.buttonEnabled = (pfObject["isEnabled"] as? Bool) ?? false
```

---

#### Optional Safety

It's really unfortunate that being safe with optionals is an optional thing at all.  It seems mostly a hold-over from the short period of time after Swift was introduced and before [Objective-C's nullability annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29401454/2792531).

Despite this, we should still strive to always be as safe as possible with our optionals.  Force-unwrapping `nil` is always a crash.

```
if(parseObject != nil) {

        if var votes: Int? = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
            votes!++

            parseObject!.setObject(votes!, forKey: "votes")
            parseObject!.saveInBackground()

            print(votes!)
        }

        delegate?.buttonClicked(self)
    loveOutlet.enabled = false

    }
```

Here, we have not been safe with our optionals.  And the worst part *here* is that there's not even an imaginably good reason for this lack of safety--we're checking for `nil` in an `if` statement and only force-unwrapping within that block.

The most dangerous problem with this is that it's not thread safe.  If thread 1 checks that `foo` is non-nil, finds it is not, then enters the `if` block, then thread 2 sets `foo` (an instance variable) to `nil`, then back on thread 1, we're in the `if` block and force unwrap, we've now crashed (despite having checked against `nil`).  This is why we should prefer the `if let` construct.

```
if let pObj = parseObject {
    // safely use pObj as a constant, unwrapped, thread-safe, locally-scoped version of parseObject
}
```

The next line is *particularly* strange.  It's a clear indication that we're aware of the `if let`/`if var` syntax, but we've used it in a mysterious and strange way.

(For the record, I absolutely never want to see `votes!++` in my code base, and if a developer on my project checked that code in, I'd be looking to move that dev to a different platform.  It's horrendous...)

You've used `if var` to properly check for `nil`... but then you specify the type as an optional which still has to be unwrapped, despite having already checked against `nil`.  If we simply don't specify the type, `votes` would be a non-optional that doesn't need to be force unwrapped.

We should also generally prefer `let` variables to `var` variables.  In fact, we should default to `let` and only change it to `var` when we absolutely must modify the value.  I don't think `votes` is something we absolutely must modify.

Finally, keep in mind we can unwrap multiple values in a single `if let` statement.  I'd prefer to see this code snippet as something more like this:

```
if let 
    pObj = parseObject, 
    votes = pObj.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
        pObj.setObject(votes + 1, forKey: "votes")
        pObj.saveInBackground()
}
delegate?.buttonClicked(self)
loveOutlet.enabled = false
```

(The actual logic for when to call `buttonClicked()` and set the outlet disabled may be slightly different, but I wanted to provide you with this example.)